# What is a name for these parenthetical phrases?

Tags: grammar, parentheticals

I recently learned about parenthetical expressions, and I just want to know if these following phrases are the ones.

> I took notes, *the elements of the story.*

And in this one.

> Victims of cancer or car accidents, once they heard my story, they
>   hobbled and wheeled over to see me, *they and their families*, though
>   none of them spoke English.

Just to be on the safe side, the phrases that are italicized are what I assume to be parenthetical phrases. "The elements of the story," and "They and their families."

In the first sentence, it seemed to me that the type of this parenthetical phrase is appositive. But I am not so sure about this. Is it appostive phrase or not?

And about the second sentence: I am just totally confused and not even sure if it is a parenthetical phrase or not. Also, I am not sure why it's "they" instead of "them". If you will tell me what it is, I will be deeply glad to receive the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by missed?

Comment: Perhaps the second example has two parenthetic phrases. One is appositive even if you were unsure. Are there any others? Adverbial for instance?

Comment: Victims of cancer or car accidents - it's one for sure.What I am confused about is "they and their families".

Comment: @yaho I would describe these sentences as badly written, with various problems.  Where did you find them?

Comment: In a book called Life of Pi by Yann Martel.

Comment: The second sentence has two appositives.

Comment: @tchrist Are these appostives "Victims of cancer or car accidents" and  "they and their families"?

Comment: Well, you have two instances of *they* and one of *victims*; those are all the same parties and the same subject.

Answer (score 1):

Parenthetical phrases are by definition incidental phrases, i.e. phrases which are redundant, unnecessary to the the construction. Not everything which follows a comma or is enclosed in two interpunction signs is a parenthetical...

The first example is just an apposition. The second is nothing: the whole *me, they and their families* is the object of the proposition.

Comment: For the latter, "they and their families" could refer to the people who hobbled, in which case it qualifies as a parenthetical phrase.

Comment: True, and that would also explain why it's *they* and not *them*; however for a "coordination" *they.. they* I'd expect a colon or semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement is definitely a parenthetical phrase. I think it's an appositive: notice that it has a noun phrase that modifies 'I took notes'; it, sometimes, can come in the middle of the sentence like "an experienced hiker" in this sentence: “If you, an experienced hiker, had trouble, how hard will it be for me?”